# Cómo puedo acceder a una imágen en específico en mi carpeta virtual?

Tags: c#

Tengo la necesidad de poder mandar un número de pedido Ó remito Ó entrega desde el `Index`, y dependiendo del que se mande buscar todas aquellas imágenes que contenga alguno de esos parámetros.

El `Index` tiene un `DropDownList` con tres opciones: "Numero Pedido", "Numero Remito" y "Numero Entrega". Cuando se completa con uno de las tres opciones, el controlador recibe la opción elegida y el valor ingresado.

```html
<body>
    <div class="text-center">
        <h1 class="display-5">Página Ejemplo</h1>
        <br>
        <div class="container">
            <h1 class="titulo">Búsqueda de facturas</h1>
            <form action="~/Home/ListaPedidos" method="post" id="form" class="form">
                <p>Seleccione campo a buscar</p>
                <div>
                    <select name="seleccion" class="select">
                        <option value="pedido">Número de pedido</option>
                        <option value="remito">Número de Remito</option>
                        <option value="entrega">Número de entrega</option>
                    </select>
                    <input class="entrada" type="text" name="identi" id="identi"/>
                    <input class="buscar" type="submit" value="BUSCAR"/>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Luego desde el controlador tengo acceso a la carpeta virtual en donde están almacenadas con `Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())`.

Cual es mi problema: No sé muy bien como hacer para poder obtener aquellas imágenes que tengan como nombre alguno de esos parámetros.

El nombre de la imagen tiene esta estructura:

[NumeroPedido]-[NumeroEntrega]-[NumeroRemito]-[NombreImagen]

**EJEMPLO**

Ingreso un "Numero Pedido"

```html
<body>
    <div class="text-center">
        <h1 class="display-5">Página Ejemplo</h1>
        <br>
        <div class="container">
            <h1 class="titulo">Búsqueda de facturas</h1>
            <form action="~/Home/ListaPedidos" method="post" id="form" class="form">
                <p>Seleccione campo a buscar</p>
                <div>
                    <select name="seleccion" class="select">
                        <option value="pedido">Número de pedido</option>
                        <option value="remito">Número de Remito</option>
                        <option value="entrega">Número de entrega</option>
                    </select>
                    <input class="entrada" type="text" name="identi" value="11111" id="identi"/>
                    <input class="buscar" type="submit" value="BUSCAR"/>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

El controlador lo recibe asi:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> ListaPedidos(string seleccion, string identi) //Llega pedido, 11111
```

Ubicacion de la carpeta:

```
var filePath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), @"wwwroot\carpetaImagenes\");
```

Entonces las imagenes que quiero recuperar de alli son todas aquellas que tengan como Numero de Pedido

**11111-[NumeroEntrega]-[NumeroRemito]-[NombreImagen]**

Y la ruta quedaria wwwroot\carpetaImagenes\11111-xxxx-xxxx-asdasd

Lo mismo pasaria si fuese Numero Entrega o Numero Imagen

En caso de que se haya ingresado el Numero Entrega las imágenes que quiero recuperar de allí son todas aquellas que tengan como Numero de Entrega:

**[Numero Pedido]-22222-[NumeroRemito]-[NombreImagen]**

wwwroot\carpetaImagenes\xxxx-22222-xxxx-asdasd

O Numero de Remito las imágenes que quiero recuperar de allí son todas aquellas que tengan como Numero de Remito:

**[Numero Pedido]-[Numero Entrega]-33333-[NombreImagen]**

wwwroot\carpetaImagenes\xxxx-xxxx-33333-asdasd

```
  [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult> ListaPedidos(string seleccion, string identi)
        {
            List<PedidoViewModel> listaPedidos = new List<PedidoViewModel>();
            string numeroPedido;
            string numeroRemito;
            string numeroEntrega;

            try
            {
                if (identi == null || identi == "")
                {
                    return View("Index");
                }

                if (seleccion == "pedido")
                    numeroPedido = identi;
                else if (seleccion == "remito")
                    numeroRemito = identi;
                else 
                    numeroEntrega = identi;

                var filePath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), @"wwwroot\carpetaImagenes\");


            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return View("Error");
            }

            return View();
        }
```

Espero que se haya entendido, cualquier duda o corrección son bienvenidas.

Answer (score 0):

Era tan simple como usar `string[] imagenes = Directory.GetFiles(@"carpeta\", "*.jpg");`. Con eso recupero todos los archivos `.jpg` de la carpeta y luego utilizo un `foreach()`.

```
string[] imagenes = Directory.GetFiles(@"carpetaImagenes\", "*.jpg");

foreach(var img in imagenes)
{
   string[] rutaSplit = img.Split("\\"); //Split aca para separar la carpeta del archivo
   string[] imagenRecuperada = rutaSplit[1].Split("_"); //split aca para lo que necesito
}
```